# Virtualbox: Pass SD card slot from Linux (Host) to Windows (Guest)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, sd-card

I am working with a Windows 10 guest OS and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as the host OS with Virtualbox. I need Windows to be able to access my SD card.

I have been using Google for hours and most guides I find do it the other way around (Windows Host, Ubuntu Guest). I’m not quite confident in my ability to reverse the directions so any help, or if anybody can point me in the direction of a guide that does this already, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the host, virt window, `Devices->USB->[SDCard]` and tick it.

If nothing there, then ensure, from the main virt window. `Settings->USB` that some version of USB is enabled.

Can't see why so many people have problems with this.

Comment: My bad. Based on some of the guides I saw to pass between Windows and Linux, I had assumed it’d be more complicated.

Comment: Ho hum, no worries. You are not the first to ask this week,